# Jasmine test if variable is not undefined

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to test my code with Jasmine. The code I want to test is:

```
window.document.cookie = 'user_input=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT';

var user_input = $('.selector').val();

if (typeof user_input !== "undefined") {
    var date = new Date;

    user_input = user_input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ');
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    window.document.cookie = "user_input=" + user_input + ';path=/;expires=' + date.toGMTString();
}
```

The test I have is:

```
describe('get_user_input', () => {
    it('should update the cookie with users input if the input is NOT undefined', () => {
        window.document.cookie = 'test_case=';
        var user_input = 'test';
        expect(window.document.cookie).toEqual('test_case=test');
    });
});
```

this however does not work and I am quite new to testing so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function gets an element from DOM. So in your tests you have to create such element in the DOM, which your function will use.

```
describe('get_user_input', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        window.document.cookie = 'test_case=';
        $("<div class='selector'>test</div>").appendTo("body");
        yourFunction();
    });

    it('should update the cookie with users input if the input is NOT undefined', () => {
        expect(window.document.cookie).toEqual('test_case=test');
    });
});
```

But **more preferable** solution would be to get rid of DOM manipulation from your function and make this function easy-testable and less-coupling.

```
function yourFunction(user_input) {
    window.document.cookie = 'user_input=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT';

    if (typeof user_input !== "undefined") {
        var date = new Date;

        user_input = user_input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ');
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        window.document.cookie = "user_input=" + user_input + ';path=/;expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
}
```

And a test for it:

```
describe('get_user_input', () => {
    let user_input;

    beforeEach(() => {
        window.document.cookie = 'test_case=';
        user_input = "test";
        yourFunction(user_input);
    });

    it('should update the cookie with users input if the input is NOT undefined', () => {
        expect(window.document.cookie).toEqual(`test_case=${user_input}`);
    });
});
```

Or even more - move `window.document.cookie` out of the function and return calculated value. And then set this returned value to `window.document.cookie` somewhere else in your app.

```
function yourFunction(cookie, user_input) {
    let res = 'user_input=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT';

    if (typeof user_input !== "undefined") {
        var date = new Date;

        user_input = user_input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ');
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        res = "user_input=" + user_input + ';path=/;expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    return res;
}

describe('get_user_input', () => {
    let cookie;
    let user_input;
    let output;

    beforeEach(() => {
        cookie = 'test_case=';
        user_input = "test";
        output = yourFunction(cookie, user_input);
    });

    it('should update the cookie with users input if the input is NOT undefined', () => {
        expect(output).toEqual(`test_case=${user_input}`);
    });
});
```

Make your function as simple as possible. Single responsibility rocks!

Comment: Thank you! This one helped me out!

Answer (score -1):

See this simple exemple [Jasmin landpage](https://jasmine.github.io/):

```
describe("A suite is just a function", function() {
  //initialisation here
  var a;

  it("and so is a spec", function() {
    //then you run the code you want to test
    a = true;
    //and you test
    expect(a).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

So with this, lets put codes in the good place:

```js
describe('get_user_input', () => {
  window.document.cookie = 'test_case=';
  var user_input = 'test';
  it('should update the cookie with users input if the input is NOT undefined', () => {

    if (typeof user_input !== "undefined") {
      var date = new Date;

      user_input = user_input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ');
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      window.document.cookie = "user_input=" + user_input + ';path=/;expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }

    expect(window.document.cookie).toEqual('test_case=test');
  });
});
```

Edit: it will not pass even with this. window.document.cookie contain the path and expires date.

```js
describe('get_user_input', () => {
      window.document.cookie = 'test_case=';
      var user_input = 'test';
      it('should update the cookie with users input if the input is NOT undefined', () => {

          if (typeof user_input !== "undefined") {
            var date = new Date;
            user_input = user_input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ');
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            window.document.cookie = "user_input=" + user_input + ';path=/;expires=' + date.toGMTString();
          }

          expect(window.document.cookie).toEqual('test_case=test;path=/;expires=' + date.toGMTString() + ');
          });
      });
```

Comment: completed answer

Comment: Sorry, but this answer didn't solve my problem. The selected answer on this thread did however. Thanks anyway!